# showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:completion: cancel button

Tags: ios, objective-c, external-accessory

is there a way to catch the cancel button event on a showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:completion:?

completion block is executed in the same <del>time</del> (way) both if i click on a device and on the cancel button.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "completion block is executed in the same time both if i click on a device and on the cancel button.", According to the doc, the analysis of the completion block will say if for example `EABluetoothAccessoryPickerResultCancelled`

Answer (score 5):

I must pay more attention when I read the docs.

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:nil completion:^(NSError *error) {
    if(error != nil && [error code] == EABluetoothAccessoryPickerResultCancelled)
        /* Cancel pressed */;
}];
```

Thanks [@Larme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1801544/larme)